# Using somesort of a switch between 230V AC and 24V DC

Tags: power-supply, switches

This is a vary basic question which will probably be answered in a blink of an eye by some of you.

I have a few hardware devices which have the same wiring schemes. The only difference is some of these devices use 230V AC and the others use 24DC.

I'd like to unify the test machine wiring and implement some sort of a switch, which I could use to switch between the mentioned two power supplies.

I was wondering how I could achieve this most elegantly? I am a comp. sci. by profession, so I'm in the dark here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really **not** recommend doing this. What if you forget to switch? It will burn your stuff in the best case or kill people in the worst.

Comment: People can't get hurt, since the power is switched on after the test is started and fuses are used in suitable places. The test device can burn only in 1/n times, since there is only one device, which needs the 24DC. I'd like to have this switch to avoid building up a redundant setup.

Comment: Somewhat related answer: using test fixtures to manage high voltage and low voltage supplies. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/209211/35022